# Filtering redux-form Actions in redux-logger with Predicate option

Tags: redux, redux-form

Can anyone offer a tip on filtering actions from Redux-Logger? I'm attempting to filter `@@redux-form/BLUR` and the like coming from Redux Form.

Based upon the Redux Logger Recipe here  https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger#log-everything-except-actions-with-certain-type

```
Log everything except actions with certain type

createLogger({
  predicate: (getState, action) => action.type !== AUTH_REMOVE_TOKEN
});
```

Based upon the recipe cited above I would expect to provide a statement with the expression formatted similarly and to return false.  I am logging successfully passing the collapsed option, so I wouldn't suspect I'm doing anything wrong in applyMiddlewear().

```
predicate:(getState, action) => action.type !== @@redux-form/FOCUS || @@redux-form/BLUR || @@redux-form/FOCUS
```

Answer (score 10):

From the creator of Redux-Logger:

```
predicate:(getState, action) => !action.type.includes('@@redux-form')
```

Full Example:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';

const logger = createLogger({
  predicate: (getState, action) => !action.type.includes('@@redux-form'),

  //...other options
});

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(logger)
);
```